# What is the difference between my .reduce concatinate and the solution?

Tags: javascript

**I feel im going crazy trying to learn from eloquent JS.  What am i missing here?**

This is my attempt:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
function concatArray (array) {
  array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
    }, []);
}
console.log(concatArray(arrays));
```

This is the solution:

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];

console.log(arrays.reduce(function(flat, current) {
  return flat.concat(current);
}, []));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the return

```
var arrays = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6]];
function concatArray (array) {
  return array.reduce(function(a, b) {
    return a.concat(b);
    }, []);
}
console.log(concatArray(arrays));
```